# Spring boot Repository query using Set - InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot API called from a React UI fetching some data using a query in the spring boot repository. However, I receive an error when I introduce the use of a Set<> to the query params and I'm unsure on how to proceed.

The error is as follows:
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [WaterHardness(id=4, hardness=hard)] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [WaterHardness(id=4, hardness=hard)] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]`

From what I have researched (I haven't found any complete examples using `ManyToMany Set<>`) I thought I should have been able to use and `IN` in the query statement along with the passed in `Set<>` parameter.

I have a controller method which takes the POST from the react app:

```
@PostMapping("/search")
@ResponseBody
public String searchFish(@RequestBody FishDto fishDto) {
    String fishJson = "";
    try {
        List<Fish> fish = fishService.findBySearch(fishDto);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        fishJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(fish);   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO Proper Handle of exceptions
        log.info("Something Went Wrong!!!");
    }
    return (fishJson);
}
```

The parameters from the call are mapped to the FishDTO:

```
public class FishDto {

    private int tankVolume;
    private int tankLength;
    private int tankDepth;
    private int tankTemp;
    private Set<WaterHardness> waterHardness;

}
```

It looks as though the DTO is populated as expected when running through with the debugger.

The controller calls a method in the service which prepares the parameters for the repository:

```
public class FishService {
    ...
    public List<Fish> findBySearch(FishDto fishDto) {
        int tankVolume = fishDto.getTankVolume();
        int tankLength = fishDto.getTankLength();
        int tankDepth = fishDto.getTankDepth();
        int tankTemp = fishDto.getTankTemp();
        Set<WaterHardness> waterHardness = fishDto.getWaterHardness();

        return Lists.newArrayList(fishrepo.findBySearch(tankVolume, tankLength, tankDepth, tankTemp, waterHardness));
    }
...
}
```

Finally the repository makes a call using a query:

```
public interface FishRepository extends JpaRepository<Fish, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT f FROM Fish f" 
        + " WHERE f.tankMinVolume <= :tankVolume"
        + " AND f.tankMinLength <= :tankLength"
        + " AND f.tankMinDepth <= :tankDepth"
        + " AND f.minWaterTemp <= :tankTemp"
        + " AND f.maxWaterTemp >= :tankTemp"
        + " AND f.waterHardness IN :waterHardness")
    List<Fish> findBySearch(@Param("tankVolume") int tankVolume,
        @Param("tankLength") int tankLength,
        @Param("tankDepth") int tankDepth,
        @Param("tankTemp") int tankTemp,
        @Param("waterHardness") Set<WaterHardness> waterHardness);
}
```

Oh and here is the Entity Model which is returned:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fish")
public class Fish {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull //Check up on this!
    private String commonName;
    private String latinName;
    private int fullGrownSize;
    private int tankMinVolume;
    private int tankMinLength;
    private int tankMinDepth;
    private int minWaterTemp;
    private int maxWaterTemp;
    private int minShoalSize;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TankPlacement> tankPlacement;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TankFlow> tankFlow;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<WaterHardness> waterHardness;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Origin origin;

}
```

Is there a neat way to get this to work beyond getting a list of either the id/string value from waterHardness in the service and passing these as a parameter and then using joins in the query? For example:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Fish f" 
        + " JOIN f.waterHardness wh"
        + " WHERE f.tankMinVolume <= :tankVolume"
        + " AND f.tankMinLength <= :tankLength"
        + " AND f.tankMinDepth <= :tankDepth"
        + " AND f.minWaterTemp <= :tankTemp"
        + " AND f.maxWaterTemp >= :tankTemp"
        + " AND wh.id IN :waterHardnessIds")
    List<Fish> findBySearch(@Param("tankVolume") int tankVolume,
        @Param("tankLength") int tankLength,
        @Param("tankDepth") int tankDepth,
        @Param("tankTemp") int tankTemp,
        @Param("waterHardnessIds") List<Long> waterHardnessIds);
```

Which does work but just feels unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `Set<WaterHardness>`.

Error says,

> Parameter value [WaterHardness(id=4, hardness=hard)] did not match
>   expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]

You need to check IN operator as follows,

public interface FishRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Fish f" 
    + " WHERE f.tankMinVolume <= :tankVolume"
    + " AND f.tankMinLength <= :tankLength"
    + " AND f.tankMinDepth <= :tankDepth"
    + " AND f.minWaterTemp <= :tankTemp"
    + " AND f.maxWaterTemp >= :tankTemp"
    + " AND f.waterHardness.id IN :waterHardness")
List<Fish> findBySearch(@Param("tankVolume") int tankVolume,
    @Param("tankLength") int tankLength,
    @Param("tankDepth") int tankDepth,
    @Param("tankTemp") int tankTemp,
    @Param("waterHardness") Set<Long> waterHardness);
}
```